# PostgreSQL trigger prevents another one to work

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, database-trigger

Suppose we have:

```
create table T
(
    id bigserial primary key
  , a  int
  , b  int
  , c  int
);
```

I want `c` to be always equals to `a+b` and I want to prevent manual changes of `c`. So I create two triggers:

```
-- Prevents manual changes of c:

create or replace function no_changes() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if old.c is distinct from new.c then
        raise exception 'Can''t change c manually.';
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger no_changes
before update of c  -- 'before' so prevents changes in 'c'
on T
for each row
execute procedure no_changes();

-- Do c = a + b:

create or replace function change() returns trigger as $$
begin
    update T
    set c = a + b
    where id = new.id;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger change
after insert or update of a, b  -- 'after' so I'm sure the row is inserted/updated
on T
for each row
execute procedure change();
```

If I do:

```
update T set c = 247;
```

I see the error message "Can't change c manually" and the column doesn't changes. Great.

However, If I do:

```
insert into T (a, b) values (4, 3);
```

Or:

```
update T set a = 3 where id = 2 -- suppose id = 2 exists
```

Then I get the same error message as before. Obviously, The `update` command from `change` trigger fires `no_changes` trigger preventing the update in the `c` column.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole logic could be placed in single function:

```
create or replace function change() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if old.c is distinct from new.c then
        raise exception 'Can''t change c manually.';
    end if;
    new.c := new.a + new.b;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger change
before insert or update on T
for each row
execute procedure change();
```

But if you prefer to split the logic, then
1) Create both triggers on `before` event
2) ["If multiple triggers of the same kind are defined for the same event, they will be fired in alphabetical order by name."](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) So name triggers to get the desired order, for example `trg1_check` to prevent changes of `c` and `trg2_change` to calculate `c` value.

Comment: Thank you, @Abelisto. Should both triggers be `before` triggers? Can't I use an `after` trigger instead?

Comment: @RicardoPérezLópez You can. But you can't change the inserted/updated row using `NEW` variable in the `after` triggers (that was the main problem of your code, `update` raises the `before update` trigger).